# How to migrate existing OU - Structure to new Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

How do I migrate an existing OU-structure from the old AD to the new Azure AD?

I have been trying to configure the Azure AD Connector Synchronization Tool for this but without success. Not sure what configuration it is supposed to have.

Anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the “old AD” is on-premise AD? In some ways, Windows Azure AD is an extension of the on-premise Active Directory, but not all features available in Azure AD. Azure AD does have a domain name, it does contain users and groups. It contains Service Principals, like on-premise AD, that represent applications. But there is no tree of domains, no trusts between domains or forests. Indeed there are no forests, no Group Policy, no OUs.

If you want to create OU, please try Azure AD Domain Services which supports to create custom Organizational Units and group policy in some limited way.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-features/

Comment: ok thanks. i really thought that OU would be supported by default. seems strange otherwise. can i make ADConnect connect to ADDS and migrate the OU's automatically? Its a lot of powershell scripting otherwise.

Comment: im going with powershell scripting everything. from what ive learned so far is that now in 2016 using "security groups" is better than creating OU with AzureAD.